*38341 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client
How can I troubleshoot the '38341 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream' error in Nginx, despite having increased both the 'somaxconn' parameter and the 'ulimit' on my server? I've followed solutions found through Google, including adjusting system-wide limits and configurations in 'nginx.conf' and 'website.conf', but the issue persists. Attached are screenshots of these configurations for referenceenter image description here
I have googled and tried and follow some steps including below
step1) fs.file-max = 2097152
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=500000
vm.max_map_count = 250000
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 500000
i have increased above parameter on /etc/sysctl.conf
step2) i have increased umlimit on /etc/security/limit.conf
root      hard    nofile       500000
root      soft    nofile       500000
But still my issue not resolved issue according to nginx log Too many files are openning and due to this my websites api response time is too slow & when i restart nginx it works sometime but please any one guide me where i am wrong and help to resolves this issue
below is the my server cpu information
lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              24
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-23
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  12
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
BIOS Vendor ID:      Intel
CPU family:          6
Model:               106
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4310 CPU @ 2.10GHz
BIOS Model name:     Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4310 CPU @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:            6
CPU MHz:             3300.000
CPU max MHz:         3300.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            4200.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           48K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1280K
L3 cache:            18432K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-23

But why would too many files be open? You need to investigate that rather than trying to increase the limit.

Run the lsof command to list open files.
Something is opening an abnormal amount of files on your server so instead of trying to change limits you should find out what is opening too many files and address that.
Further reading: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/linux-lsof-command/
